# Powershell: Is there a filepath for Powershell Functions similar to OuterClass$InnerClass.class?

Tags: powershell, filepath, azure-powershell

I come from a java background and I am now using powershell in Azure Environments. Is there some equivalent of the file naming for java classes in powershell? In java the outer/inner classes are named like this in the file path:

```
OuterClass.class
OuterClass$InnerClass.class
```

Say I have a powershell file with several different functions in the file `C:\powerShellScripts\scriptTest.ps1`. Is there a similar naming convention for powershell functions?

```
function test () {
    Write-Output "This is the test function!"
}
function apple () {
    Write-Output "This is the apple function!"
}
function green () {
    Write-Output "This is the green function!"
}
```

I'm assuming it would be something similar, such as `C:\powerShellScripts\scriptTest$apple.ps1`

I want to specify a singular function to call on a VM remotely. I have a hundred or so functions defined in a singular file, and only need to call a few of them. So I wanted to know If I could specify a singular function to call remotely, or if it only supports for a whole script file.

Comment: You can 'dot source' your library script (e.g. `. C:\powerShellScripts\scriptTest.ps1` - note the extra dot and space at the beginning), then call the specific function by name (e.g. `apple`).  You might want to investigate converting your script to a [PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-7.1) - properly written and 'installed', you will have access to the functions at the PowerShell prompt automatically, like the built-in cmdlets.

Comment: @boxdog hey thanks. The cmdlets I am trying to use [`Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmcustomscriptextension?view=azps-6.0.0) or [`Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-6.0.0) require a script. Is there a way that I could just call a specific function? Like only `apple` and not also `green` and `test`?